Run Lubuntu 24.04.1 off DVD, freezes during startup
Old Fujitsu laptop, Intel T2130, 2GB RAM.
Boot up from Lubuntu DVD, select "Run or install". DVD whines for a while, then PC freezes on black screen.

Is this laptop is the wrong architecture for a 64 bit OS https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/30769/intel-pentium-processor-t2130-1m-cache-1-86-ghz-533-mhz-fsb/specifications.html and does the iso even fit on the DVD

Thx Graham. So -- is there a 32-bit Linux variant available? Otherwise, I just going to throw it away

you may find this answer to a related question useful

Lubuntu provides an image only for amd64 architecture; older releases that are EOL provided images for i386 (how Debian and Ubuntu refer to x86 32-bit) & armhf (32-bit ARM), but no supported Ubuntu release will run on 32-bit x86 (i386) with only 32-bit ARM now supported. Debian still provides 32-bit x86 (i386) ISOs, though they are may not provide i386 media for their next release either (but will support current releases until they reach EOL ~5 years from initial release)

That computer is 32-bit, this distribution may work fine: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mx-linux/files/Final/Xfce/MX-23.4_386.iso/download

This question is similar to: Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How do I obtain an Ubuntu CD for my 32-bit PC and notebook? and Will ESM also become available for14.04 and later LTS releases? (Covers 2022). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
